# Sitecore Commerce Service Proxy and Microsoft oData Compatibility Issue XC 10.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm trying to use commerce service proxy, and when trying to update connected services I'm getting the following build error, noticing that I'm using XC 10.1 and  MS oData 7.5:

```
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>' to
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>' Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy
C:\deploy\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.7.0.55\src\Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy\Connected
 Services\CommerceOps\CommerceOps.cs
```

Looking into this and it seems like an issue with oData and fixed in 7.6.3 as stated here:
https://github.com/OData/odata.net/pull/1648
Upgrading Nuget fix the build error but when deploying the service proxy it breaks the storefront which is using oData 7.5.

Could be VS extension issue, I've VS 2019 with oData v 0.12.0, couldn't find any reference what version should be used with 10.1, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I used to get same error in Sitecore 9.3 in visual studio 2019 with latest OData.

It only worked when i switched to visual studio 2017 with OData Connected Service 0.3.0.
Here is the link with error and other details: https://sitecore-commerce.blogspot.com/2020/11/sitecore-commerce-service-proxy-error.html

For 10.1 it should work with Visual Studio 2019 with latest version of OData Connected Service.
Try with deleting "CommerceOps.cs" and "CommerceShops.cs" file and verify "ConnectedService.json" file for ServiceName, Endpoint. Then re-generate service proxy and see if there error is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS2019 with Odata Connected Service 0.12.1.
You will always get this error with latest extension but you need to make sure you execute Sitecore provided Powershell script to update the proxy.

After you have updated the OData connected service, find update-proxy.ps1 in you project and execute it.

```
../Commerce.SDK/src/Sitecore.Commerce.ServiceProxy/Connected
Services/update-proxy.ps1
```